# iPhone Cordova - Tap on input field shows and immediately hides keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, ios7, cordova-3

I'm using cordova to build an app for ios.

I have a strange error. When i tap on an input field on my iPhone 4S, sometimes the keyboard opens and hides immediately. This error occurs after the first time always again, till i leave the page and return to it, then it might have vanished. I haven't seen this error neither on my iPad nor on any Android device.

Both devices are using iOS 7. I updated cordova already to 3.1.0. Furthermore I'm using jQuery (version 1.10.2) and jQuery Mobile (Version 1.3.2).

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I looked at the bugtracker for cordova 3.2.0 and there is a [critical bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5002) which mentions something similar.

Comment: Still no clue how to fix this, please help